# Yocto Dunfell setting root password in recipe unsuccessful

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

I am trying to set the root user password in a custom recipe for yocto Dunfell.

Recipe looks like this: I have also tried `EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS_append` as shown in some other stackOverflow posts and it also did not work.

```
SUMMARY = "Test"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

# Remove debugging tweaks
IMAGE_FEATURES_remove += " \
    debug-tweaks \
"
# Add root password, and add the 'test' user
inherit extrausers

EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = " \
    usermod -P testpasswd root; \
    useradd -p '' test \
"

FILES_${PN} = " /test/temp \
"

do_install () {
        install -d ${D}/test/tmp
}
```

If I build this with my recipe, I can login as root with no password and when I check `/etc/shadow` the test user is not created.

I have verified that my desired directory `/test/temp` is created.

Answer (score 1):

You should also remove **allow-empty-password** and **empty-root-password** features from IMAGE_FEATURES if they maybe available. [enter link description here](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/2.5/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-features-image)

and You didn't use semicolons at end of **useradd -p '' test** . This can cause error.

And you should be sure that debug-tweaks is not added at other strong files like local.conf